# Ruby on Rails Popen output conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, popen

I'm stuck trying to convert an array to a string.  Ultimately, what I need to do is:

1. Convert the array to string
2. Remove the `\n` characters
3. Remove the quotes
4. Place each line on a newline in the view

I should also say that I'm trying to do this without creating a temp file to read from.

**tools_controller.rb**

```html
def ping_host(host)
  f = IO.Popen("ping -c 3 #{host}")
  @output = f.readlines
  return @output
end
```

**views/tools/ping.html.erb**

```html
<%= @output %>
```

This works fine and dandy, however, the output presented in the view leaves much to be desired:

```html
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes\n", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.614 ms\n", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.716 ms\n", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.658 ms\n", "\n", "--- 10.10.10.1 ping statistics ---\n", "3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss\n", "round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.614/1.663/1.716/0.042 ms\n"]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get it into a format like this:

```
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.614 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.716 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.658 ms
--- 10.10.10.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.614/1.663/1.716/0.042 ms
```

Which strips out all of the quotes and newlines and present in console like fashion to the user, but on a webpage instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
def ping_host(host)
  f = IO.Popen("ping -c 3 #{host}")
  @output = f.readlines
  return "<pre>#{@output.join}</pre>".html_safe
end
```

Comment: Snazzy!  As I'm good at doing... I was making it too complicated!